# jEdit plugin best practise

Tags: jedit

Which plugin could be example of the best jEdit plugin? In terms of the code, the use of tests.

I've made Markdown plugin and want to update it. This plugin has no any tests and uses a singleton. Which plugin can I use as example?

Comment: Have you tried asking on the jedit-devel list (https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/jedit-devel)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an example of the "best" jEdit plugin.
It always depends on what you try to implement how to do it.